# Highcharts moving average based on visible data only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

So, I have a price time series I wrote a moving average for the prices of different retailers https://i.stack.imgur.com/N17yS.png . So far so good, but I want to only see the moving average of the visible retailers. For example, here I have only one shop shown, but the moving average is calculated on all of them. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3XJV.png  Is it possible to make it to dynamically change? Maybe reload the graph or something?

Comment: Have you tried to set [visible](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.visible) as false, per each serie, which should be hidden?

Comment: How are you calculating the moving average? If you have a function in javascript to calculate it, you can use the legendItemClick event to trigger the function, and you can set a clause to use only visible series to calculate from

Comment: No, I generated the data in ruby, and just added it. I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example based on my comment above.

This example does not calculate a moving average - I wrote a simple function to calculate the overall average for the sake of simplicity.

The purpose of the example is to demonstrate how to do it on `legendItemClick`, making use of only the visible series.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/gejgquxh/